# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

`I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException  when I run the testcase in Eclipse. Can somebody help me in pointing out the error I have made.`

Error @ Line 17: WebElement in LoginPage.Java.
@ Line 12: LoginPage in TC_LoginTest_001.java.

```
**LoginPage.Java**

package com.internetBanking.pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class LoginPage {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public LoginPage (WebDriver driver) {
            
        this.driver = driver;
        
    }
    
    WebElement usrname = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));
    WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin"));
    
    public void setUsrname(String uname) {
        usrname.sendKeys(uname);
    }

    public void setPwd(String pswd) {
        pwd.sendKeys(pswd);
    }

    public void login() {
        
        login.click();
    }

}

**TC_LoginTest_001.java**

package com.internetBanking.testCases;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.internetBanking.pageObjects.LoginPage;
public class TC_LoginTest_001 extends BaseClass {
    
    @Test
    public void LoginTest() {
                
        driver.get(baseURL);
        logger.info("URL is opened");
        
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        
        loginPage.setUsrname(username);
        logger.info("Username is entered");
        
        loginPage.setPwd(password);
        logger.info("Password is entered");
        
        loginPage.login();                                         
        logger.info("Login button is clicked");
        
    }
}
```

When I run the test case, I am getting the below errors:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.internetBanking.pageObjects.LoginPage.(LoginPage.java:17)
at com.internetBanking.testCases.TC_LoginTest_001.LoginTest(TC_LoginTest_001.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: Did you initialize your web driver? Do you have something like this : driver=new ChromeDriver(options); befor you are searching for the elements?

Comment: Driver.get is working ? In login test ?

Answer (score 1):

**Consider this code:**

```java
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(new Object());
    }
}

class Test {
    InitMe initMe = new InitMe();
    public Test(Object o){
        System.out.println("Test instance has been created");
    }
}

class InitMe{
    public InitMe(){
        System.out.println("Init me instance has been created");
    }
}
```

If you run it you will see the following output:

```
Init me instance has been created
Test instance has been created
```

which means that fields are initialized before the constructor is executed. So in your case you have the following structure:

```java
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(new Object());
    }
}

class Test {
    Object o;
    String oStr = o.toString();
    public Test(Object o){
        this.o = o;
    }
}
```

where your fields are initialized through the reference that has not been yet initialized itself (because the constructor has not yet been called).

**Your particular solution would be** to change this:

```java
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public LoginPage (WebDriver driver) {
            
        this.driver = driver;
        
    }
    
    WebElement usrname = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));
    WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin"));
```

to this:

```java
    WebDriver driver;
    WebElement usrname;
    WebElement pwd;
    WebElement login;
    
    public LoginPage (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        usrname = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));
        pwd = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        login = driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin"));}
    }
```